# How do I get the (html) id from the select tag on rails_admin?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

The 'rails_admin' generate this HTML below, I need to change the options of another 'select' tag depending on which 'option' is selected in this 'select' tag, with a coffescript/jquery.
The id= of this 'select' tag is "schedule_tasks_attributes_1532831082497_service_id".
How do I get this id with this number inside? This is not a fixed number.

```
<div class="form-group control-group belongs_to_association_type service_field "id="schedule_tasks_attributes_1532831082497_service_id_field">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="schedule_tasks_attributes_1532831082497_service_id">Service</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 controls">
    <select data-filteringselect="true" data-options="{&quot;xhr&quot;:false,&quot;remote_source&quot;:&quot;/admin/service?associated_collection=service\u0026compact=true\u0026current_action=create\u0026source_abstract_model=task&quot;}" placeholder="Buscar" name="schedule[tasks_attributes][1532831082497][service_id]" id="schedule_tasks_attributes_1532831082497_service_id" style="display: none;">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="5">Service 5</option>
      <option value="4">Service 4</option>
      <option value="3">Service 3</option>
      <option value="2">Service 2</option>
      <option value="1">Service 1</option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-group filtering-select col-sm-2" data-input-for="schedule_tasks_attributes_1532831082497_service_id" style="float: left;">
      <input type="text" class="form-control ra-filtering-select-input ui-autocomplete-input" style="display: inline-block;" placeholder="Buscar" required="required" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <label class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Show All Items" role="button">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span>
          </label>
        </span>
      </div>
      <a data-link="/admin/service/new?modal=true" class="btn btn-info create" style="margin-left:10px" href="#">
        <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
        Add new service
      </a>
      <a data-link="/admin/service/__ID__/edit?modal=true" class="btn btn-info update disabled" style="margin-left:10px" href="#">
        <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
        Edit service
      </a>
      <span class="help-block">Required. </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following codes in jquery to select the mentioned select tag.

1. `$("[id ^='schedule_tasks_attributes_']")`
2. `$("[id $='_service_id']")`

In your case for perfect selection, you can use this:-

```
$("select[id ^='schedule_tasks_attributes_'][id $='_service_id']")
```

Comment: This code list all IDs started with schedule_tasks_attributes_, OK... but on page  are other elements with this initial. It is a cute workaround... ^ and $ is regex?

Comment: No Carlos, these are CSS selectors which are allowed in jQuery too.

Comment: @CarlosFagianiJr I have updated the answer. You can check it now, and let me know if still, you face any issue. Feel free to comment here or skype me personally at connect.ronit

Comment: @CarlosFagianiJr Happy to help ... :)